# Facebook login firebase and cordova, simple login having white screen

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

Okay I have checked so many question for days now and there is not decent answer for this question.

I have tried the [firebase-simple-login-phonegap](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login-phonegap) example, and it works perfectly on browser but when I build it using phonegap, in android platform, it only shows me a white screen.

I assume that the cordova.js file was for ios platform as i have seen in the source code, but where is the one for android.

I have downloaded the `android_js` from the repo, i have seen the cordova.js file there but I can't just copy it because it has dependencies, and gave me an error of

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

What do I do?

Comment: Hi, there! I just wanted to know if you managed to discover what was wrong, as I am currently experiencing the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I have not been able to resolve it, atleast from that time, and I used local authentication instead of integrating facebook, I opened the issue in their github account and it seems like that it's a version issue: see : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-phonegap/issues/5#issuecomment-39685345